# I've already added tools.jar in classpath, why still java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap thrown?

Tags: osgi, classloader, javassist

I'm using the HotSwap function of [javassist](http://www.javassist.org/), it requires tools.jar in classpath, so I added `-cp tools.jar` when start my OSGi appliction. But when I `new HotSwap()` in the code of one of the bundles,

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap
```

was thrown. `com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap` is in the tools.jar and I've already added it in classpath and also I verified it worked because if not, the following code will not work:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

The Classloader of HotSwapper cannot load class`com.sun.jdi.Bootstrap`? Then why it works properly in my Eclipse environment?(I added tools.jar into the libraries of Build path)

On why NoClassDefFoundError, any clue is appreciated.

Comment: osgi have a concept of "execution environments", which is a list of packages. Your osgi framework will not allow you acess something that from system bundle.

Comment: Running in Eclipse is a bit different, eclipse is more relex because it need all those develer stuffs.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ thanks, but how can I access this? Because `HotSwapper` needs it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Equinox, you can set Boot Delegation to `*` to gain acess to all class in bootclass, see [this wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Boot_Delegation) for details. In 3.2, it was `osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true` in `config.ini`.

Comment: And if you do that you largely lost the advantage of modularity because you punctured a big hole in it ...

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure the system bundle exports this package. For example in Felix the file jre.properties defines what packages are exported by the system bundle. Add the package com.sun.jdi there and it should work.

In eclipse this is done in config.ini. You can use org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra= to define additional packages to export. I would rather not use boodelegation=* as it might export unwanted packages too. See:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/734358/

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Boot_Delegation

Comment: I cannot find such a `jre.properties` file in my Equinox environment. Which folder will it be like in or what inside it? I can search in folder.

Comment: For equinox like for eclipse it is a property org.osgi.framework.system.packages that you can set to export the desired packages. If you only want to add packages to the default ones use org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra